# How to escape characters in Firebase Functions?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a Firebase Function to take an uploaded picture in Storage and create a circular thumbnail from it. Everything works but the actual ImageMagick command.

I get an error:
[image]

Code:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec(`convert ${tempLocalFile} -resize x300 -resize 300x< -gravity center -crop ${THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT}x${THUMB_MAX_WIDTH}+0+0 +repage \( +clone -threshold -1 -negate -fill white -draw "circle 150,150 150,0" \) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite -auto-orient ${tempLocalThumbFile}`, { stdio: 'ignore' }, (err, stdout) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error('Error conveting image to thumbnail.', err);
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve(stdout);
          }
        });
      });
```

I am assuming this is caused by parenthesis being a special character that needs escaped. How do I escape the parenthesis in my command? I tried the first time without the `\` in front of the parenthesis, but it resulted in the same error.

Comment: Please don't show images of errors and code.  Copy them into the question so they're easier to read and searchable on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really specific to Firebase, but it's because your command produces a single parenthesis instead of `\(`, which is [what's required by ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#parenthesis).

To fix it, change

```
... +repage \( +clone -threshold -1 -negate -fill white -draw "circle 150,150 150,0" \) ...
```

to

```
... +repage \\( +clone -threshold -1 -negate -fill white -draw "circle 150,150 150,0" \\) ...
```

which should produce the correct string. Essentially what needs to be done is you need to print out the backslash `\`, but since that's the escape character, that's the character that needs to be escaped, so the command should use `\\` instead.